# Replicate Activemq Message to once server to another server activemq

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

Q: we want publish same message in different Activemq servers. can we have any approach. like we will publish once and activemq changes will give a forward that message to another instance.

or is there any way we can do it by the activemq config changes?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much context in the question but a simple Topic together with [Network of brokers](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html) should do that.

The idea is that you connect multiple brokers using "network of brokers", then [messages sent to a topic will be available to all clients on all brokers throughout the network](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-distributed-queues-or-topics.html).

There are a lot of corner cases when it comes to network of brokers and topics, but it should do the work.